# Does increasing the index cause the write IOPS of AWS RDS to rise?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Does increasing the index cause the write IOPS of AWS RDS to rise?

The AWS RDS I use is db.m3.xlarge . The storage of RDS is 50G.

Now the write IOPS of AWS RDS is 120

50G RDS write IOPS peak is 150

According to the Official document :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html

Baseline I/O performance for General Purpose SSD storage is 3 IOPS for each GiB, which means that larger volumes have better performance.

How do I query the reason why RDS write IOPS rises?

Comment: What do you mean by "increasing the index"?

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer this by dividing it into two parts :

**Do I have a I/O Problem ?**

**Finding reason behind high write IOPS on MySQL (RDS) server ?**

---

**Do I have a I/O Problem ?**

When using AWS RDS, one does not have traditional OS tools such as systat, iostat, dtstat or sar. The tool to understand what is happening in RDS is cloudwatch metrics and the graphs provided.

- **Read and Write IOPS metrics**: 
  By summing up the ReadIOPS and WriteIOPS you will see how much IOPS your operations consume.
- **DiskQueueDepth Metric**: The DiskQueueDepth metric provides the number of outstanding IOs (read/write requests) waiting to access the disk. If this metrics is frequently above 2, then you should expect sooner or later to face performance issues.

Using the above two graphs it is easy to identify if you are under-provisioned or over-provisioned in IOPS.

1. If your `DiskQueueDepth` is consistsently between **0** and **0.5** you are over provisioned.
2. If your `DiskQueueDepth` is consistsently above **2** then you are under provisioned.

---

**Finding reason behind high write IOPS on MySQL (RDS) server ?**

There are several ways to profile your queries, but as you are using RDS with MySQL , I would recommend you to use `PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA` to do it easily, as you won't need external software (some of which is not fully RDS-compatible).

You can refer to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXToUv6W62E&t=8m45s) with an introduction to query profiling, with examples like IOPS and temporary table creation monitoring by query pattern, user and table. For a more specific guide (specially for configuration of metrics), you can have a look at the [official manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema.html) and the [sys schema documentation](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys).

If you need to have quick look what is going you can have quick look at the `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS like 'com\_%'`; and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS like 'Hand%'`; at time interval to see if you have an increase on the number of SQL queries per unit of time or on the number of engine row operations per unit of time.

---

To Conclude, an increase on Write `IOPS` normally may mean extra SQL load (obviously), but also many other things, such as,too many temporary tables or worse query plans being executed due to a change on the query optimiser plan or on your data cardinality/size. It is critical to identify the underlying cause first before taking any action.

Hope this Helps you !

Comment: when you say DiskQueueDepth  should be between 0.5 -2 is it average , sum, sample count in statistic ?